# (Typo?): Find the minimum value of the function $x^3+y^3-3xy$.

Tags: calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, book-recommendation

I am preparing for the ***GRE Math Subject Test***. One of the books that I like for this test is ***GRE Math Subject Test (Advanced) - By Morris Bramson - 1983***. It is a very old book, available online but with poor scanning quality. However, I believe, it contains awesome/tricky problems that may be useful to prepare for the GRE.

---

I am not sure if this question is stated in the right way or not.

---

Find the minimum value of the function $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3xy$.

$\text{(A) 0} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \text{(B) -1} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \text{(C) -2} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \text{(D) 1} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \text{(E) 2}$

---

Originally from the book:
[image]

---

I know the way to solve easy max/min problems.

$f_x=3x^2-3y$, and $f_y=3y^2-3x$. Equating these partial derivatives to zero and solving the system of equations, we get

$(x,y)=(1,1)$ as a critical point. Now evaluating $f(1,1)=1^3+1^3-3(1)(1)=-1$. Hence $\text{(B)}$ is correct (as mentioned in the book).

However, this is not "*the minimum*". This is "a" local minimum. The function has no minimum because we can set $y=0$ and $x$ as small as we like.

---

Excuse me for my poor English (I am Arabic). What do you think? Am I right that the function has no minimum and that the question is not stated in a right way?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Indeed you are right!

Comment: I think what they wanted to say was when $x,y\ge 0$ in which case am-gm yeilds $x^3+y^3+1\ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3\cdot 1}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. Is changing the statement to "Find the minimum value of the function $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3xy$, where both $x$ and $y$ are positive." a valid change? Or that will lead us to a more complicated approach (e.g. Lagrange's multiplier)?

Comment: Then the problem becomes harder.

Comment: The only way to make this problem a GRE math problem for just solving the derivative to zero is by asking "Find all stationary points of $x^3+y^3-3xy$" or "Find all local extrema of $x^3+y^3-3xy.$" Of course, the wording with "find all..." confuses non mathematicians.

Answer (score -1):

Let's $f = x^3 +y^3-3xy$.

Then,
$$f = x^3 +y^3+1^3 -3 \times x \times y \times 1 -1\\
\Rightarrow f = (x+y+1)(x^2+y^2+1-xy-x-y)-1 \\
\Rightarrow f = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+1)((x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)  -1 $$

To minimize $f$, the term $(x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$ must be minimized as it is always $\geq 0$ *i.e.*

$$(x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\geq 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow min((x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2) = 0$$
As $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$, $(x-1)^2 \geq 0$ and $(y-1)^2 \geq 0$, the above equation splits into
$$ \Rightarrow \bigg( min \big((x-y)^2 \big) +min \big((x-1)^2 \big) +min \big((y-1)^2 \big) \bigg) $$
$$ \Rightarrow \bigg( x-y=0, x-1=0 \text{ and } y-1=0 \bigg) $$
$$ \Rightarrow x=y=1 $$
so that $(x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 = 0$ which is its minimum value.

This minimum value will be achieved by making $(x-y)^2=0$, $(x-1)^2=0$ and $(y-1)^2 = 0$.

Thus, $min(f) = \frac{1}{2}(1+1+1) \times 0 -1 = -1$